# VBScript - Don't know why my arguments are not used the same way as variables

Tags: vbscript, variables, arguments

I have written a VBScript to enumerate events from the event log on a particular day.

The first query select from the NT event log events between todays date and yesterdays date,

```
Set colEvents = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent Where TimeWritten >= '" _ 
        & dtmStartDate & "' and TimeWritten < '" & dtmEndDate & "'")
```

Then from the query above i want to extract event id's from a log file.

```
For Each objEvent in colEvents
    If objEvent.Eventcode = EventNu And (objEvent.LogFile = EventLog) Then
```

I have placed the following into the script and it works, however I want to use arguments instead via command line (i.e. EventLogCheck.vbs EventNumber LogFile )but if i use the arguments secion of the script no items are returned. This is driving me nuts. The full script below uses variables, i have commented out the arguments section, but you can uncomment them and play around with it. What am i doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

```
Const CONVERT_TO_LOCAL_TIME = True
Dim EventLog

EventNu = 18
EventLog = "System"

'Input from the command line
'If Wscript.Arguments.Count <= 1 Then
'   Wscript.Echo "Usage: EventLogCheck.vbs EventNumber LogFile"
'   Wscript.Quit
'End If

'EventNu = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
'EventLog = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)

'For Each Computer In Wscript.Arguments

Set dtmStartDate = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
Set dtmEndDate = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
'DateToCheck = CDate("5/18/2009")
DateToCheck = date
dtmStartDate.SetVarDate DateToCheck, CONVERT_TO_LOCAL_TIME
dtmEndDate.SetVarDate DateToCheck + 1, CONVERT_TO_LOCAL_TIME

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colEvents = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent Where TimeWritten >= '" _ 
        & dtmStartDate & "' and TimeWritten < '" & dtmEndDate & "'") 

For Each objEvent in colEvents
 If objEvent.Eventcode = EventNu And (objEvent.LogFile = EventLog) Then
    'Wscript.Echo "Category: " & objEvent.Category
    Wscript.Echo "Computer Name: " & objEvent.ComputerName
    Wscript.Echo "Event Code: " & objEvent.EventCode
    Wscript.Echo "Message: " & objEvent.Message
   ' Wscript.Echo "Record Number: " & objEvent.RecordNumber
   ' Wscript.Echo "Source Name: " & objEvent.SourceName
    Wscript.Echo "Time Written: " & objEvent.TimeWritten
    Wscript.Echo "Event Type: " & objEvent.Type
   ' Wscript.Echo "User: " & objEvent.User
    Wscript.Echo objEvent.LogFile
   End if
Next
'Next
WScript.Echo EventNu
WScript.Echo EventLog
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arguments passed are treated as being of type string. However, EventNu should be an integer. You therefore have to convert the arguments to the correct type using [`CInt`](http://www.w3schools.com/VBScript/func_cint.asp) and [`CStr`](http://www.w3schools.com/VBScript/func_cstr.asp):

```
EventNu = CInt(WScript.Arguments.Item(0))
EventLog = CStr(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))
```